# How to solve the below WIN - MAC vba compatibility issue?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The below VBA code is working on Win Excel but not on Mac Excel. Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue ? When opening the excel file on Mac the following message appears (translated from french): "compilation error - method or data member cannot be found". And it is not possible to use the excel file.

The first line is highlighted from "Private" to "Range)"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect([B4:B20], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
    Set f = Sheets("BD")
    a = Application.Transpose(f.Range("A3:A" & f.[A65000].End(xlUp).Row))
    Me.ComboBox1.List = a
    Me.ComboBox1.Height = Target.Height + 3
    Me.ComboBox1.Width = Target.Width
    Me.ComboBox1.Top = Target.Top
    Me.ComboBox1.Left = Target.Left
    Me.ComboBox1 = Target
    Me.ComboBox1.Visible = True
    Me.ComboBox1.Activate
  Else
    Me.ComboBox1.Visible = False
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 If Me.ComboBox1 <> "" And IsError(Application.Match(Me.ComboBox1, a, 0)) Then
   Me.ComboBox1.List = Filter(a, Me.ComboBox1.Text, True, vbTextCompare)
   Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
 End If
   ActiveCell.Value = Me.ComboBox1
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Me.ComboBox1.List = a
  Me.ComboBox1.Activate
  Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Let me know if wrong but I believe the code is in the Worksheet object:

[image: VBA Screenshot]

Thanks for your help,

Comment: maybe you should explain the issue in your question? "it doesnt work on a mac" is not a question.

Comment: When opening the excel file on Mac the following message appears (translated from french): "compilation error - method or data member cannot be found". And it is not possible to use the excel file.

Comment: well, that's not "in your question" - but now the next thing to explain is which line is highlighted when you get the error - it really would be better to just add all this to your question.

Comment: @braX thanks for your time, patience and answers. 100% rookie in here.

Comment: Maybe you aren't putting it in the worksheet object and instead you put it into a module? It won't work in a module.

Comment: Well I would tend to think its in the worksheet object. I added a screenshot in the post to help visualize.